# Is there a jQuery plugin that combines lightbox and slideshow (Google Buzz-style)?

Tags: jquery-plugins, lightbox, slideshow, image-gallery

When you click on an image in Google Buzz, it shows this image in a lightbox, but at the bottom of the screen there is a list of all images in the same context (and you can click or scroll through it).

I want to use the same functionality in my gallery, but I prefer not to spend a lot of time building it.

Is there a plugin that provides same or similar functionality (not just back/forward, but a list of other thumbnails)?

Comment: This May Solve Your Problem http://fancybox.net/

Comment: In this one I do not see an option to show a list of other thumbnails below the image.

Comment: [FancyBox2](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) now supports this.